# Client Id is not setting while using OAuth2RestTemplate to invoke rest api in spring

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to invoke the `Oauth2` secured rest API from my client appliaction using `Oauth2RestTemplate`

The client `Id` is not setting while trying to get the access token

Please help me to get the sample code or link to working code

`AppConfig.java`

```
@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails getOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails()
{
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    details.setAccessTokenUri("External Url , Ex: https://XXX/oauth2/v0/token");
    details.setClientId("*******");
    details.setClientSecret("******");
    details.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    return details;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2RestTemplate  createOAuth2RestTemplate() {

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(getOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessToken));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

In `ClientInvoker.java`

```
String URL= "Get the Accounts Url";
oAuth2RestTemplate.getForEntity("URL", Object.class)
```

> Exception
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate]:
>   Factory method 'createOAuth2RestTemplate' threw exception; nested
>   exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Access token
>   denied."  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: error="access_denied",
>   error_description="Access token denied."  at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have issues with your resource server. Confirm the following

1. Its pointing to the same **authorization server/instance** as your **client**.
2. Confirm that the **expiry window** on the clients token is no less than **1ms**(lol).. yes yes.. please check.

Regards